# jquery ajax append from another url in my domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Hey guys I'm trying to figure out how to append divs from different urls. Problem is is that I need multiple urls that change, in the sense let me explain.

I have 5 urls;

/u1stats

/u1

/u1friends

/u1contact

/u1wall

Now the 1 would change per persons links, such as u2 u3 u4 u5 and so forth. I tried doing /u but thing is i need specifics from stats friends contact and so forth. How exactly would i make it so that the code would call to the corresponding u(number)stats basically??
Or is this just not possible at all.

This is the Ajax I tried from the ui page

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Also would the #result be the div I want to .load to the /test.html inside of #container or

```
#container from /test.html to #result?
```

Sorry for if you can't understand me, I'll answer any and all questions

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Will load the page `ajax/test.html`, grab the element with the id `container`, and load that content into the element with the id `result` on the current page.

Assuming the javascript is run on the page `http://www.example.com/u1`, you can automatically load the content from the four other urls (ie `http://www.example.com/u1contact`, `http://www.example.com/u1friends`, etc) using the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = parseInt(window.location.pathname);
    $('#result').load('u' + i + 'contact #container');
    $('#result').load('u' + i + 'friends #container');
    $('#result').load('u' + i + 'stats #container');
    $('#result').load('u' + i + 'wall #container');
});
```

and then call loadUserInfo('1'), loadUserInfo('2'), etc...

Comment: what does + i + do? will i have to input the data of 1 2 3 4? I mean many users will come so I'd need it to just get that data that is in the url if it is 1 or 2 or 1234.

Comment: What do you mean get that data that is in the url? Do you want to pull data from /uXcontact, /uXfriends, /uXstats, and /uXwall when the user is on the page /uX? Where X is any number like 1, 2 or 1234?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes content from a designated url and optionally a selector found within and `loads` it into the preceding selector. So the `#container` element in `ajax/text.html` will be loaded into `#result` on the page on which you run the script.

I'm not sure how the `u*` urls correlate to your `ajax/test.html` `load` source, but you could pass your load function a variable that corresponds to the url you want to load, so in order to load the `#container` from `/u1stats` you could do the following:

```
function loadUserInfo($url) {
    $('#result').load($url + ' #container');
}

loadUserInfo('/u1stats');
```

Then you could also use `loadUserInfo('/u1friends');` or `loadUserInfo('/u2contact');`

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question or what you're trying to do.

Comment: trying to make it so i don't have to type in 1. Since I won't know what user is looking at the data information. If say user 12345 which would then be /u12345 i'd need the script to automatically register that the url we are seek is from u12345